# Matlab matrix multiplication returns values that it shouldn't

Tags: matlab, matrix, floating-point

I have a problem using matrix multiplication in Matlab.

I have a 8x4 matrix called `A` and a 4x1 vector called `B`. Looking at matrix `A`, the fourth row of has the values

```
A(4,:) = (-19.723654104483987, -73.609679228848705,  73.609679228848705,  19.723654104483987)
```

and the vector B has the values

```
B = (101325,      101325,      101325,      101325)'.
```

It appears to me that these two, when multiplied, would cancel eachother out. However, when I use `A*B` = `ans`, the fourth row of `ans` has a value as shown below.

```
ans(4) = 4.656612873077393e-10
```

I find this strange since I tried to check if the elements of A(4,:) and they really should cancel out since

```
(A(4,1) == -A(4,4)) = 1
(A(4,2) == -A(4,3)) = 1
```

and

```
(B(1) == B(2)) = 1
(B(1) == B(3)) = 1
(B(1) == B(4)) = 1
```

I was thinking that it might have something to do with the machine epsilon of Matlab, but the answer is larger than e-16.

Another thing I find strange is that when I use `A(4,:)*B` it returns 0. Why does a value appear on the forth row when using full scale matrix multiplication?

If anyone has an idea why this doesn't return zero, I would be grateful!

Comment: YOu're multiplying numbers of the order of 1e5 with others of the order of 1e2, I would say that the result being in the order of 1e-10 is pretty much 0.

Answer (score 2):

You are computing an expression

```
((-a+(-b))+b)+a,  a,b > 0
```

Floating point operations are not commutative, the truncation error committed by the first addition of `-a` and `-b` is not undone by the second addition of `b`, so the third addition of `a` will not land at zero, but will reflect the truncation error of the first sum. So it is not surprising that you get a residual error of size `(a+b)*mu`, `mu` being the machine constant, about `2e-16`. As your `a+b` is about `1e+7`, this conforms with the actual result you got.

See also the many resources provided in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Specific reference Q for MATLAB floating point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!